# Cannot run command pyb from Pybuilder in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, pybuilder

I wanted to reactivate an old python project I worked on two years ago.

I wanted to recreate the same working conditions with one difference: when I developed at the time i worked on Ubuntu WSL (win10) with virtualenvs. Now I want to work directly from windows 10 using Anaconda.

commands in Anaconda prompt (admin rights) I entered

```
conda create -n env python=3.6
conda activate env
pip install pybuilder==0.11.17
pyb
```

this is where the error occurs. I get it in german but it's s.t. like
`"The command "pyb" is either spelled wrong or doesn't exist"`

Note that all my relevant files for the project (namely build.py) are already present and I execute the command in the correct directory. Although I don't think that's the issue since command is not even recognized.

`pip list` confirms pybuilder is installed correctly and `where python` tells me the first python it uses is from the correct environment.

I strongly assume it has s.t. to do with Anaconda, since i was able to successfully redo it under Ubuntu WSL (win10) conditions again.

---

**Edit**: i made it work using the absolute path to the conda environment and executing pyb_.exe. However the file pyb* is present too. I'd still be interested to know why the anaconda prompt is not able to execute it.

---

Appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.
Cheers!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. You meant `pip install pybuilder==0.11.17`, right? `-r` seems to be a typo.

Comment: yes, i changed midway from installing via requirements file to pybuilder only because it made my question more clearly. Thank you!

Comment: Does the `pip` actually point to the one corresponding to the activated environment?

Comment: yes, ```where pip``` yields "C:\...\anaconda3\envs\env-name\Scripts\pip.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this as I have found a satisfying solution:

- I tested my code with updated packages (pip) and it still worked.
- pybuilder==0.13.3
- tried `pyb`again in the anaconda prompt and it executed without problems

since this is merely an issue with outdated software I'll mark this as answered